# Get User Properties By Id

Tags: 2013, client-object-model, user-profile-property, rest

I am having trouble finding documentation on how to query for user properties via JSOM or CSOM using a SP UserID. I must be missing something because SharePoint returns an ID for the user involved in nearly every scenario whether it is a social action or list item.

Does anyone know the method or URI to query for user properties using the SharePoint Id as a parameter?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Rest API URI:

```
http://<site url>/_api/web/getuserbyid(ID#)
```

Dev Center article:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn531432(v=office.15).aspx#bk_User