# How to get SharePoint users from list by Rest API

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, spfx, user-profile, spfx-webparts

I have written my app, in SharePoint Framework, but in link I have got only name of list. How can I get user name and Surname of editor and creator?

[image]

I want to have all user data. How can I get it by using Rest API?

Comment: I need Name Surname and Photo of User

Comment: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/109805/get-user-properties-by-id

Answer (score 2):

You can use REST endpoint like:

```
<siteUrl>/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('TestList')/items(1)?$select=Title,Author/ID,Author/Title,Author/LastName,Editor/ID,Editor/Title,Editor/LastName&$expand=Author,Editor
```

This will give you:

- Author ID
- Author Title (Full Name)
- Author LastName
- Editor ID
- Editor Title (Full Name)
- Editor LastName

---

Then using `ID` you got from above endpoint, you can request profile picture like:

```
<siteUrl>/_api/Web/Lists/getByTitle('User Information List')/items?$filter=Id eq <User ID>&$select=Picture
```

OR using `SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager` (Check 2nd reference link):

```
/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetPropertiesFor(accountName=@v)?@v='<accountName>'&$select=PictureUrl
```

---

**References**:

1. [How to get users picture field displayed via _api/Web/Lists - SharePoint Online](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/117260/how-to-get-users-picture-field-displayed-via-api-web-lists-sharepoint-online)
2. [How to Retrieve User Profile Properties(eg Picture) Using REST SharePoint](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/e8665952-edd7-4da4-9ac5-f4fa32616e06/how-to-retrieve-user-profile-propertieseg-picture-using-rest-sharepoint)

Comment: Great, but how get this user to the code. Please @Ganesh Sonap

Comment: You can call first (/items) endpoint, which will give you the list items & respective author/editor ID. Then in `success` function of first API call, inside for loop (for each result), you can get the profile picture for respective user by passing `ID` you got from 1st API call.